# Optimization with "add to 1" constraint in optimization variable

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to formulate an optimization problem using `scipy minimize` function. However, I am having the following problem that I can't work around:

I want `X = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` that minimizes a cost function F(X). This X vector, however, are percentage values that must add to 1, i.e., `np.sum(X) = 1`.

The problem is: if I use, for instance, the "SLSQP" method with some initial values (such as `X0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]`), it will try to increment each value to find some convergence direction. For example, the algorithm will make `X0 -> [0.21, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]`. But that cannot happen, because `np.sum(X) = 1` is a requirement for me to compute the objective function.

Using constraints does not help either! I could make a constraint with `np.sum(X) = 1`. However, the minimize algorithm will only check the constraint after computing the objective function.

Anyone have an idea on how to deal with such a problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use `F(X/sum(X))` as objective. One remaining issue: all `x=0`. Return a large obj for that case.

Comment: Amazing Erwin, that is it! Can you please post as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Have you come across Augmented Lagrange Multiplier? It can save you the hassle by converting your constrained optimization to unconstrained optimization :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NLP solvers I typically use will not ask for function and gradient evaluations when X is outside its bounds. That means we can protect things like `sqrt(x)` and `log(x)` by adding appropriate lower bounds.

Constraints can not be assumed to hold when we evaluate functions and gradients.

If your function assumes `sum(X)=1`, you could call `F(X/sum(X))`. The only complication is when `X=0`. In that case, return a large value for F so that the solver will move away from it.

Comment: Btw, in my case, I can't have any Xi = 0, so the X=0 is not a problem. But that could be a problem indeed.

Answer (score -1):

The *must sum to 1* constraint effectively reduces the number of variables you need to optimize. If you know the value of all but one of your variables the remaining value is implied by the constraint. It must be exactly `1 - sum(other_vars)`

Instead of optimizing five variables `X = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` you can optimize four variables and compute the fifth: `X = [x1, x2, x3, x4, 1 - (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)]`.

This formulation of the optimization problem avoids imprecisions that might arise if all X are very low.

If the variables are percentages you will want to specify lower and upper bounds of 0 and 1, respectively.
Furthermore, you will need to constrain `x1+x2+x3+x4 <= 1` to avoid negative `x5`. (This *inequality* constraint is much easier for optimizers than the original *equality* constraint.)

```py
def cost_function(X):
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = X
    x5 = 1.0 - (x1, x2, x3, x4)    
    return F((x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))

x0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]  # initial guess: all values equal
minimize(cost_function, x0, 
         bounds=[(0.0, 1.0)]*4, 
         constraints=dict(type='ineq', fun=lambda X: 1.0 - X.sum()))
```

Comment: Similar answer to a very different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45712241/3005167

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @kazemakase. The problem in doing ```1 - sum(other_vars)``` is that if we have, for instance, x1 = 0.7 and z2 = 0.8, which will result in a negative x5.

Comment: I think this approach has the same (or similar) deficiency the original post was about. Solvers do not obey constraints for all iterations. Although, in this case, the summation to one is always obeyed, now the bounds on x5 are not honored (until at the end of the run when the problem is optimal -- and feasible). So we are just swapping one kind of infeasibity for another.